# Libgit2sharp, Pushing a specific branch to new remote

Tags: git, .net-core, libgit2sharp, aws-codecommit

I am writing a dotnet api to clone from github, then push a specific branch to AWS codecommit using the Libgit2sharp library.

- I have two branches in the gitHubRepo, origin/release and origin/refactor.
- origin/release is the DEFAULT git branch
- I want to clone the gitHubRepo, and push the origin/refactor branch to codecommit

**Problem**:
I can't seem to get it to push my specified branch to codecommit, it always seems to push what is set to HEAD. I don't know how to change the HEAD, or even know if this is the issue.

Code Snippet:

```
var baseRefBranch = gitHubRepo.Branches[$"origin/refactor"];
if (baseRefBranch == null) throw new Exception("refactor branch was null...");

logger.LogInformation($"Checking out branch: {baseRefBranch.CanonicalName}");
Commands.Checkout(gitHubRepo, baseRefBranch);

logger.LogInformation($"Update branch {baseRefBranch.CanonicalName}, set remote name {codeCommitRemote.Name}, set upstreamBranch to {baseRefBranch.CanonicalName}");
        gitHubRepo.Branches.Update(baseRefBranch,
            b => b.Remote = codeCommitRemote.Name,
            b => b.UpstreamBranch = baseRefBranch.CanonicalName);

var refSpec = $"+{baseRefBranch.CanonicalName}";
logger.LogInformation($"Trying to push to remote: {codeCommitRemote.Name}, refSpec: {refSpec}");
gitHubRepo.Network.Push(codeCommitRemote, refSpec, pushOptions);
```

Any help appreciated... Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use a [complete refsepc when pushing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_options_a_id_options_a)

> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.

In your case:

```
+refs/heads/refactor:refs/heads/refactor
```

Comment: Thanks so much, in my case since refactor branch was not a HEAD, I had to do `+refs/remotes/origin/refactor:refs/heads/refactor` This works, thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!